# sorting mysql table by data within a different table

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have to mysql tables and trying to display results of table1 but sorting by table2. For table2 I'm counting all the occurrences of a duplicate id and then display that result descending. Below is as far as I could get and wondering if this can even be done is a single query.

```
$query = "
SELECT DISTINCT   registration.* 

FROM              registration 

INNER JOIN        downloads 
ON                registration.id = downloads.id 

GROUP BY          downloads.COUNT(id) 
ORDER BY          downloads.COUNT(id) DESC,
                  downloads.COUNT(id) DESC
```

";

Comment: Your query is full of problems.  It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  Perhaps some example data and your desired results would help to illustrate your requirements?

Comment: Table 1 has id number, name, email. Table 2 has id number, download ducument.  Trying to display id number, name, email, download document and order by the largest number of downloads.

Comment: Just so you know, the MySQL 'feature' that allows you to `SELECT` columns not part of a `GROUP BY` or aggregate functions (eg `COUNT()`) is inherently dangerous - you can't control what values you get in the extra columns.  This means that any time the DB decides to optimize your query in a different way, you can get different results...

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want something along these lines:

```
SELECT Registration.id, Registration.name, Registration.email,
       Downloads.document
FROM Registration
JOIN Downloads
  ON Downloads.id = Registration.id
JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) as count
      FROM Downloads
      GROUP BY id) Download_Count
  ON Download_Count.id = Registration.id
ORDER BY Download_Count.count DESC
```

(untested, as it would be nice for the OP to supply sample data and table layouts in the question)